# shouldn't std::sync::Mutex::get_mut() be unsafe

Tags: rust

Docs say

> Returns a mutable reference to the underlying data.
> Since this call borrows the Mutex mutably, no actual locking needs to take place – the mutable borrow statically guarantees no locks exist.

So the problem is **no locking needed**. Sure, if the mutex (in)directly is not used from any unsafe block then it is not possible any thread holds a reference on it and therefore can't use it. That also means, in order to compile the call of get_mut, if any thread was using it the thread must already finish its execution. It is also fine that any new thread will access the data protected by the mutex, because it will be read from the memory as if acquire semantic, so any changes made with data via get_mut will be visible to any new thread.

However, if a mutex was used from an unsafe block, it is possible that some thread (likely ffi like in my case) still has a pointer on the mutex and can either hold the lock and use data or just finish mutating the data and unlock the mutex. In the former case, it is clearly UB, in the latter case, it is a race condition, which is also UB, because the thread, which calls get_mut, might not see the latest state of the protected data, which was just updated by another thread, which accesses the mutex through the pointer. In order to make the latest changes visible on the thread calling get_mut acquire/release semantic should be held, but get_mut doesn't call any acquire operation.

get_mut is a useful function as it is but I don't believe it is thread-safe and therefore should be unsafe.

Comment: There's a relatively simple reasoning for `get_mut` being safe: You cannot use it to produce races/UB without unsafe code. That's it. Hence, there must be a hole in your reasoning somewhere.

Comment: Recall the type system! `get_mut` requires a mutable reference to the `Mutex`. If you hold a mutable reference to the `Mutex`, then nobody else holds any references to it, period. And since there are no other references to it, there can be no race condition. Hence, no locking is needed.

Comment: Note that this is not a separated example, but rather a pattern that occurs often anywhere where you have an interior mutability. For example [std::cell::Cell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) has method [Cell::get_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.get_mut) which allows you to get a mutable reference to item inside cell, as long as you have an _exclusive_ reference to the cell itself.

Comment: @alter_igel "And since there are no other references to it, there can be no race condition" Rust borrow checker doesn't know anything about threads and race conditions. Having mut ref implies no other refs but that doesn't imply that CPU having access to the protected data is actually seen the latest version. To guarantee that you have to synchronize access to the protected data with the LATEST mutex UNLOCK operation. As I said it is not needed if there are no unsafe code == POINTERS, but if you have a pointer you can write a SOUND program that exposes race condition without lock.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a593759ea82e268a03a3ae9bfb83f308)? You think there is an UB because there is no _aquire_ between the last _release_ and the access of the `get_mut()`, isn't it?

Comment: @AntonDyachenko Can you write a MRE that demonstrates the UB?

Comment: @AntonDyachenko `"Rust borrow checker doesn't know anything about threads and race conditions"` -> yes it does, read up on the [`Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html) and [`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) traits.

Answer (score 6):

The main property of mutable references in Rust is that they are [unique](https://limpet.net/mbrubeck/2019/02/07/rust-a-unique-perspective.html). That is, when the code as a whole is sound, it is guaranteed that the *only* way to access the value referenced by the mutable reference is through that exact reference. In safe code, this is enforced automatically. In the unsafe code, including FFI, that's the invariant *you*, as the one writing `unsafe`, are expected to uphold.

In particular, when you have the mutable reference to the `Mutex`, it's explicit and immediate UB to have any other place access the same mutex or the data behind it. In particular, it's essentially UB to have it locked by anyone else, since the unlock would, by definition, access the mutex (to store the "not locked" bit).

So, if some `unsafe` code leads to `get_mut` being non-thread-safe, then this unsafe code is itself unsound.

Comment: Isn't it already UB once you create the two mutable references? I.e., no need to actually access anything.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the case when we have not two mutable references, but e.g. `&mut T` and `*mut T`. The _existence_ of these at the same time is not UB, but actually _using_ the raw pointer while the reference is active definitely is.

Comment: What can you use the raw pointer for without creating a reference?

Comment: [`core::ptr::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/ptr/fn.write.html), for example.

Comment: as usual, people fighting with the weak argument - simultaneous access / not unique reference first case, but completely ignoring the strong argument - my second case. In my second example, there are NO references when a mut ref is used, BUT because another thread has just finished mutation through ref under the lock, this thread that getting data via get_mut and the ONLY mut ref will not see the latest version of the data, because it doesn't lock the mutex. So, in my second example, nothing is unsound but race condition is present -> UB -> unsafe.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko Accessing shared memory using raw pointers without proper memory barriers or other synchronization **is** unsound. I'm not sure why you think it's  not.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko Sorry to say it bluntly, but your arguments are pretty much irrelevant since yes, unsafe can produce UB. Not a problem. But to dissect: You say "there are no other refs when mut is used" without really defining what "when" means (Rust lacks a memory/aliasing model…). Simultaneity doesn't exist, especially not between processes on different cores. If you look at it differently: to know that there were no other refs, you need synchronization. If you have none, the refs might have in fact existed at the same time, and might have is enough for UB.

Answer (score 4):

If you are only using safe code, then the mere existence of the mutable reference implies that you have a happens-before relationship, thus synchronization, at compile time.

If you are using unsafe code to access the lock, then *you* are responsible to make sure there is a happens-before relationship. If you don't do that, your code is unsound even without actually changing the data, because you're creating  two overlapping mutable references without synchronization, therefore UB. So *you* are responsible for creating proper synchronization. If you do it, everything is fine. If you don't, *your* unsafe code is unsound and the UB comes from *your* unsafe code. std's `get_mut()` plays no role here, and therefore is sound.

Answer (score -3):

The answer to my question is, yes, sure it should be unsafe. Run this on ARM (x64 works fine because of strong memory). There are exactly 2 unsafe blocks and all the safety conditions for them are met therefore it is a sound (from the borrow checker point of view) code but it is not thread-safe. Replacing both get_mut onto the lock solves the problem as expected.

```
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicPtr;
use std::sync::atomic::Ordering::*;
use std::sync::Mutex;

static RX: AtomicPtr<Mutex<i32>> = AtomicPtr::new(std::ptr::null_mut());
static TX: AtomicPtr<Mutex<i32>> = AtomicPtr::new(std::ptr::null_mut());
const COUNT: i32 = 64 * 1024 * 1024;

fn main() {
    let t = std::thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut current = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let mut m;
        for i in 0..COUNT {
            loop {
                match RX.compare_exchange(current, std::ptr::null_mut(), Relaxed, Relaxed) {
                    Ok(ptr) if !ptr.is_null() => {
                        m = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) };
                        break;
                    }
                    Ok(ptr) | Err(ptr) => current = ptr,
                }
            }
            assert_eq!(m.get_mut().unwrap(), &-i);
            *m.get_mut().unwrap() = i;
            TX.store(Box::<_>::into_raw(m), Relaxed);
        }
    });

    let mut m = Box::new(Mutex::new(0));
    for i in 0..COUNT {
        *m.get_mut().unwrap() = -i;
        RX.store(Box::<_>::into_raw(m), Relaxed);
        let mut current = std::ptr::null_mut();
        loop {
            match TX.compare_exchange(current, std::ptr::null_mut(), Relaxed, Relaxed) {
                Ok(ptr) if !ptr.is_null() => {
                    m = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) };
                    break;
                }
                Ok(ptr) | Err(ptr) => current = ptr,
            }
        }
        assert_eq!(m.get_mut().unwrap(), &i);
    }
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

PS: I decided to put an extra explanation here as comments do not really work for this. Let's look at `Arc::drop` and their comments

```
   fn drop(&mut self) {
        // Because `fetch_sub` is already atomic, we do not need to synchronize
        // with other threads unless we are going to delete the object. This
        // same logic applies to the below `fetch_sub` to the `weak` count.
        if self.inner().strong.fetch_sub(1, Release) != 1 {
            return;
        }

        // This fence is needed to prevent reordering of use of the data and
        // deletion of the data. Because it is marked `Release`, the decreasing
        // of the reference count synchronizes with this `Acquire` fence. This
        // means that use of the data happens before decreasing the reference
        // count, which happens before this fence, which happens before the
        // deletion of the data.
        //
        // As explained in the [Boost documentation][1],
        //
        // > It is important to enforce any possible access to the object in one
        // > thread (through an existing reference) to *happen before* deleting
        // > the object in a different thread. This is achieved by a "release"
        // > operation after dropping a reference (any access to the object
        // > through this reference must obviously happened before), and an
        // > "acquire" operation before deleting the object.
        //
        // In particular, while the contents of an Arc are usually immutable, it's
        // possible to have interior writes to something like a Mutex<T>. Since a
        // Mutex is not acquired when it is deleted, we can't rely on its
        // synchronization logic to make writes in thread A visible to a destructor
        // running in thread B.
        //
        // Also note that the Acquire fence here could probably be replaced with an
        // Acquire load, which could improve performance in highly-contended
        // situations. See [2].
        //
        // [1]: (www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic/usage_examples.html)
        // [2]: (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/41714)
        acquire!(self.inner().strong);

        unsafe {
            self.drop_slow();
        }
    }
```

So now, I have an even stronger opinion about the whole unsoundness of `std::sync::Mutex`. Only the lock family of methods of mutex are ok, `get_mut` and `drop` are not thread-safe. Remember the whole point of Mutex abstraction is to provide thread-safe access via public safe API -> ensuring any public safe method has a happens-before relationship among each other in ANY safe scenario.

Back to `Arc::drop` it is already having a scratch to workaround bug in the `Mutex::drop`. If `Mutex::drop` would ensure the happens-before relationship with all other `Mutex` public safe API functions then `Arc` could use simple relaxed ordering for every type.

1. Let's imagine that `T` in `Arc<T>` has no interior mutability then by rust language guarantee it is always safe to use relaxed order on the counter because the only access to the protected data is load.
2. Let's imagine that `T` in `Arc<T>` exposes interior mutability then either `Arc` should ensure the happens-before relationship (which c++ `std::shared_ptr` does and mimicked by rust) or (which is much more logical) the type T with interior mutability has to ensure happens-before relationship in its public safe API.

Now, because of the wrong responsibility distribution between `Arc` and `Mutex` design choice, all other code similar to `Arc` has to mimic that bad design and ensure the happens-before relationship.

Another argument, what is the ratio of `Arc::drop` calls over `Mutex::drop` calls in an ordinary program? I bet much less than 1. Therefore it is even more optimal to ensure the happens-before relationship in `Mutex` rather than in everywhere else, at the end of the day this is what `Mutex` abstraction should do in a safe language like rust.

Again having &mut ref doesn't assume any happens-before relationship on the PROTECTED data it only guarantees the absence of any other refs, and in my example, this is the case. Remember the internal structure of the `Mutex` it contains `UnsafeCell` and `sys::Mutex`, in my example with relaxed order ANY operation on the `sys::Mutex` is thread-safe, and it is guaranteed by `sys::Mutex` implementation, but access to `UnsafeCell` isn't and requires happens-before relationship, that what `Mutex` for isn't it?

In other words, if you deconstruct `Mutex` abstraction into a pair of `sys::Mutex` and `UnsafeCell` and pass a pointer over this boxed pair then after converting the pointer back to reference you can safely use `sys::Mutex` part in all scenarios but you can't do this with `UnsafeCell` without ensuring happens-before relationship.

PPS: Basically, all the arguments, from people who downvoted this answer, could be narrowed down to one simple sentence:

In rust, it is illegal to use `std::sync::AtomicPtr` with `std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed` in any safe code.

I can leave with and accept this point of view when this will be encoded in the rust type system.

Comment: No, your code is unsound and is its execution is outright UB. As I said in my answer, you have two `Box`es pointing to the same memory at the same time. **This is UB.** The fact that it might not be at the same time physically doesn't matter, since on the abstract machine it _is_ one the same time (as there is no synchronization), and this is the only thing that matters.

Comment: If you're convinced that `get_mut` should be `unsafe`, then please provide a code example that uses `get_mut` _without using unsafe code_  that is unsound.

Comment: Again, `get_mut` is safe because **it can't be used to create unsound code in safe rust.** If you are already accessing the `Mutex` from multiple mutable references or pointers, then you are already working in unsafe code, and it is **your responsibility** to uphold soundness guarantees.

Comment: @alter_igel This is not entirely correct; an unsafe code might be considered unsound even if it can only be used to cause UB by unsafe code, _iff_ that unsafe code is sound. Of course, the definition of soundness is conventional. There are some things that are obviously unsound, but some are not and are arguably are sound or not. In this case, like I said, this code is unsound according to the rules, but even without this, we generally consider std code to be sound and therefore we assume that code that unsafe triggers UB with std code is unsound.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman "it might not be at the same time physically doesn't matter" doesn't make sense to me as you basically just said any multithread code that shares anything is UB.

Comment: No. I'm saying that multithreaded code that shares anything **without proper synchronization** (and of course, mutates it too, or at least creates a mutable reference) is UB.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman ok then "you have two Boxes pointing to the same memory at the same time" is incorrect if you referring to real/physical time, I used CAS specifically to be able to demonstrate that there are EXACTLY 1 not null pointer to the boxed mutex at any given physical time moment.

Comment: But again, **physical time does not matter**. We are not running in the physical world - we are running in the Abstract Machine world. And in that world, things from two threads are interleaving unless there is proper synchronization (a happens-before relationship) within them.

Comment: You contradict yourself, please decide whether it doesn't matter -> no sync code in rust is sound, or it does matter and in order to be safe unsafe code needs to provide proper synchronization. These two points of view are mutually exclusive, you need to fix this in your mind.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I actually have to agree with the OP that there is no aliasing here, relaxed memory ordering is not allowed to violate causality on an object. That said, fundamentally this still boils down to a misunderstanding of ordering.

Comment: @AntonDyachenko `TX` sees a non-null pointer but it does so with relaxed ordering. There are no guarantees you'll see _anything_ else from the thread, such as modifications to the pointee. The RX thread has no guarantee to see `-i`, for example, so that assertion failure is not a bug. Likewise with the `TX` thread reading `i`. All this demonstrates is that relaxed reads are, in fact, relaxed. Reading stale values is not a safety issue.

Comment: @GManNickG your comments are the only valuable here as you really understand the problem. Now replace this toy example with a real code where these pieces (flags and mutex) are very much separated and written by different people at different times. So each person making changes could be sure its changes are absolutely fine, but the overall result is not. That is why I am sure that get_mut with the current implementation should be unsafe. It is possible to provide a safe get_mut that makes sure the synchronize-with relationship is held even without locking the mutex. See Arc::drop as an example

Comment: @AntonDyachenko You haven't addressed anything I stated, and threw in an insult on top of that. Why are you bringing up irrelevant details like who writes what part of the code? This is basic memory ordering. But, if you already know the answer then good on you, just don't bother asking the question.

Comment: @GManNickG see https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/glossary.html#validity-and-safety-invariant "it is relevant when arguing whether some library is sound" is my point about "irrelevant details like who writes what part of the code". Again, both unsafe blocks extracted into functions "is sound if it is impossible for safe code to cause Undefined Behavior using its public API". Just converting a pointer into a reference in these unsafe blocks doesn't cause UB. But the access by the reference via get_mut (lock is fine) does. Mutex by itself uses unsafe blocks so get_mut isn't safe

Comment: @AntonDyachenko I've never said that having no synchronization is fine (assuming you mutate the object).

Comment: @GManNickG Are you referring to modification order consistency? It does not not synchronize the code between, and this is what creates the aliased `Box`. And for what it's worth, thread sanitizer does report data race here.

Comment: @GManNickG And for what it's worth, Miri also agrees with me. It reports a data race not with the actual write, but with the creation of the aliased `Box`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah, I agree! I forgot drops are considered writes in Miri, even if `ManuallyDrop` is used. This is to match the C++ memory model and hence TSAN. (Which is unfortunate since Rust has an opportunity to refine the memory model, but realistically it's not gonna happen.) Of course, even if this code were switched to raw pointers it would still immediately hit UB for same reasons we've been trying to explain, just merely one atomic operation later.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am guessing this version is probably closest to what OP is imagining in their head: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8493a086a2444568daf0d3903da568f. I don't know if they'll find this any easier to understand...but it drills down to the same old issue: UB due to aliasing, per lack of memory ordering.

Comment: "Let's imagine that T in Arc<T> has no interior mutability then by rust language guarantee it is always safe to use relaxed order on the counter because the only access to the protected data is load" - and load must happen before deallocation (we don't want use-after-free, right?). How could you guarantee that without requiring that load happens before this atomic fence?

Comment: "Remember the whole point of Mutex abstraction is to provide thread-safe access via public safe API -> **ensuring any public safe method has a happens-before relationship among each other in ANY safe scenario**" - this is not true, and was never guaranteed (look at the docs). The only guarantee is that you cannot cause data race in safe code, or in properly synchronized unsafe code. And it is upheld.

Comment: "Now, because of the wrong responsibility distribution between Arc and Mutex design choice, all other code similar to Arc has to mimic that bad design and ensure the happens-before relationship" - and if the opposite would be chosen, all code of interior mutability primitives similar to `Mutex` would have to add code for that. And there are many more for it, since there are many more possible ways to protect from data races but there is one simple way to implement a reference-counted pointer.

Comment: And let's say you're right and `Mutex::drop()` should've synchronize (which I disagree). That only means std has chosen the wrong abstraction. It certainly doesn't mean it is unsound. You'd need much stronger proofs for that. This is a decision to be made, and it was made by std.

Comment: Also, all the discussion about `Drop` is not related to the discussion about `get_mut()`. Perhaps `Mutex::drop()` is wrong (not outright wrong, just slightly wrong). `get_mut()` is still correct. _Even if we'd want `get_mut()` to protect against data races, it just cannot do that_. As it is given a `&mut` reference, and as I've explained, even the mere existence of one in a non-synchronized context is a plain UB, even before (or without) calling `get_mut()`.

Comment: "In rust, it is illegal to use std::sync::AtomicPtr with std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Relaxed in any safe code" - Depending on how you use it. This is not unique to Rust. C++ has the same rule.